# Change public folder location in Zend_Framework project?

Tags: php, zend-framework, directory, public

I want my public_html folder on my server to be the public folder in my zend project.
You guys any idea how I can do this? Right now I have to view my site with domain.com/public

I tried changing the index.php file to this (changed the directories)

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . 'application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . 'library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea how I can get this fixed?

Basically I want a directory structure like this:

```
public_html/
----application/
----library/
----index.php
```

Or is there some other way to achieve this? I want 'public' gone from my URL anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your .htaccess is set up right you dont have to worry about people getting to your library folder, simple rewrite rules can prevent that.

Below is what ive used to get rid of the public directory on my index.php

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$dirs = array(
        $path . '/library',
        get_include_path()
);
$includes = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $dirs);
set_include_path($includes);

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
        || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));

defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
        || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

$application = new Zend_Application(
                APPLICATION_ENV,
                APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
```

and this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule \.svn/.* index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the wrong approach! The reason why we have a public folder and almost everything else is on the same level is a reason of security! We don't want to have our libraries and application code in our public folder!

The only thing you need to change is your server (apache) vhost configuration so that it points to your public folder as the document root.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /path/to/your/public/folder
ServerName domain.com
    <Directory path/to/your/public/folder>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm on a shared host with no access to do that. Also, in this particular case, Zend is running on a subdomain. like `sub.domain.com` `sub` is just a folder inside the `public_html` folder, so every Zend folder can be accessed through `domain.com/application` anyway..

Comment: not necessarily the case. as long as you set up the htaccess right along with the file permissions, you shouldnt have much to worry about

Comment: Even shared hosters offer private directories where you can put code in.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/05/08/zend-framework-shared-hosting/) suggests one pretty easy approach (essentially, remove `public` and push all the ZF files into a sub-folder), but it also references several other approaches.

In particular, the comments on that post suggest that you can simply modify the `.htaccess` file at the root of your subdomain to push all requests down into the public folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.* /public/$0 [L]
```

Then in the `public` folder, you keep the standard `.htaccess`. In the worst case, you also have to set the `baseUrl` of the app during `Bootstrap`, probably via config.